# How to create a column for each level of another column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, calculated-columns

The goal I am trying to achieve is an expanded data frame in which I will have created a new column for each level of a specific column in R. Here is a sample of the initial data frame and the data frame I am trying to achieve:

**Original Data Frame:**

```
record           crop_land     fishing_ground
BiocapPerCap     1.5           3.4
Consumption      2.3           0.5
```

**Goal Data Frame:**

```
crop_land.BiocapPerCap     crop_land.Consumption     fishing_ground.BiocapPerCap      fishing_ground.Consumption
1.5                        2.3                       3.4                              0.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `pivot_wider` from the `tidyr` package as follows.

```
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "record", values_from = c("crop_land", "fishing_ground"),
              names_sep = ".")
dat2
# # A tibble: 1 x 4
#   crop_land.BiocapPerCap crop_land.Consumption fishing_ground.BiocapPer~ fishing_ground.Consumpti~
#                    <dbl>                 <dbl>                     <dbl>                     <dbl>
# 1                    1.5                   2.3                       3.4                       0.5
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "record           crop_land     fishing_ground
BiocapPerCap     1.5           3.4
Consumption      2.3           0.5",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using tidyr is one option.

`tidyr::pivot_longer()` converts `crop_land` and `fishing_ground` to variable-value pairs. `tidyr::unite()` combines the record and variable to new names.
`tidyr::pivot_wider()` creates the wide data frame you are after.

```
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr) # for %>%

tst <-  data.frame(
  record = c("BiocapPerCap", "Consumption"), 
  crop_land = c(1.5, 2.3), 
  fishing_ground = c(3.4, 0.5)
)

pivot_longer(tst, -record) %>% 
  unite(new_name, record, name, sep = '.') %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = new_name, values_from = value)
```